# Does Azure App Configuration even for Kubernetes managed ASP .NET Core apps?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, kubernetes, azure-feature-manager

I'm reading this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x

I cannot find information if this approach is also valid if my application is hosted on pods via Kubernetes not by AppService? Will I be able to steer feature flags values via Azure App Configuration? I don't think so.